# Windows 8.1 store apps architecture

Tags: windows-8, architecture, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm wondering if this architecture is possible for an Windows Store application.

To resume briefly, i have a main apps which contain components (those can have view/ViewModel...). Those components are accessible via an hub in the main project. To ensures maintainability, i'd like to order my components as subprojects of my solution. I'd like to be able to debug through subproject.

Here is an example :

1. Solution

   1. MainProject (hub)
   2. subProject1 (hubtile1)

      1. views
      2. viewModels
   3. subProject2 (hubtile2)

      1. views
      2. viewModels

... and so on.

**The question is** : how to achieve that ?
Is it possible to include a subproject as view with viewmodel linked in ? in that way i (or other) could dev each subproject separately. 
If it's possible will my subProject would be able to discuss with each other (like subProject1 wants to share some infos with subProject2) ?

Thanks in advance for any hint :-)

Comment: I think these would just be folders within the main project.

Comment: that's what i did :( its kinda ok

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a project for every single hub. It's not best practise and will slow down Visual Studio. I saw such a project...

I would suggest a structure like:

BusinessLogic (project)
DataAccess (project)
UI (project)
  Assets
  Controls
  Pages
  Styles
  UserControls
  ViewModels

With this approach you'll also preventing to have too many namespaces.